# How to use Poco::ZIP to compress/decompress zip file

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I new to C++ especially in compress/decompress. My current project is using the Poco Library and the Zip extensions are used to compress or decompress the file/directory to a Zip file.

```
#include <Poco/FileStream.h>
#include <Poco/Zip/Decompress.h>
#include <Poco/Zip/Compress.h>
#include <Poco/Timestamp.h>
#include <Poco/File.h>
voidZipFile(string source, string target, List extensions, bool append, bool overWrite)
{
    Poco::DateTime(Timestamp);
    set <string> extensionsSet;
    std::ofstream fos(target, ios::binary);
    Poco::Zip::Compress c(fos, true);

    for (int i = 0; i < extensions.Size(); i++) {
        string ext = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<String>(extensions.operator[](i))->GetPrimitive();
        extensionsSet.insert(ext);
    }
    c.setStoreExtensions(extensionsSet);//set extensions List 

    Poco::File aFile(source);//This is where I start my compress action

    if (aFile.exists())
    {
        Poco::Path p(aFile.path());
        if (aFile.isDirectory())
        {
            if (p.isDirectory()) {
                c.addDirectory(p, Poco::DateTime());
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        else if (aFile.isFile())
        {
            c.addFile(p, p.getFileName());
        }
    }
    else {
        _log.EndMethod();
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File Not Found");
    }


    //Poco::FileOutputStream fos(target, std::ios::binary);

    c.close(); // MUST be done to finalize the Zip file
    fos.close();


}
```

The above code is what I have so far and I can compress a single file into a `.zip` file.

How do I compress a folder/directory into a .zip file? I cannot use another library because Poco is used for other parts of my current project also.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a recursive way to search through the folders.

This is what I thought of:

```
Poco::File aFile(entry);
        if (!aFile.isDirectory())
            throw ZipException("Not a directory: "+ entry.toString());
        Poco::Path aName(name);
        aName.makeDirectory();
        if (!excludeRoot)
        {
            if (aName.depth() == 0)
            {
                Poco::Path tmp(entry);
                tmp.makeAbsolute(); // eliminate ../
                aName = Poco::Path(tmp[tmp.depth()-1]);
                aName.makeDirectory();
            }

            addDirectory(aName, aFile.getLastModified());
        }
    // iterate over children in the directory
        std::vector<std::string> children;
        aFile.list(children);
        std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = children.begin();
        std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator itEnd = children.end();
        for (; it != itEnd; ++it)
        {
            Poco::Path realFile(entry, *it);
            Poco::Path renamedFile(aName, *it);
            Poco::File aFile(realFile);
            if (aFile.isDirectory())
            {
                realFile.makeDirectory();
                renamedFile.makeDirectory();
                addRecursive(realFile, cm, cl, false, renamedFile);
            }
            else
            {
                realFile.makeFile();
                renamedFile.makeFile();
                addFile(realFile, renamedFile, cm, cl);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try and if it help I would mark your answer as an acceptable answer. Thanks a lot Paul.

Comment: `if (!excludeRoot)` @Paul can you help me explain about this line what is excludeRoot, I can't come up with anything.

Comment: It adds a directory entry recursively to the zip file  excluding the parent directory.  Reference https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Zip.Compress.html

Comment: I see, but where does `excludeRoot` come from, I don't see any const or value that is `excludeRoot`

Comment: You would require to pass excludeRoot(bool) to your function voidZipFile. It would be like voidZipFile (const Poco::Path &entry, ZipCommon::CompressionMethod cm, ZipCommon::CompressionLevel cl, bool excludeRoot, const Poco::Path& name)

Comment: Ahh, so I just need to call the `AddRecursive` method of `Compress` it's already defined for us.