# Poco addRecursive Not Returning to Normal Program Flow

Tags: c++, directory, compression

I implemented Poco in my C++ application for Windows in VS 2019 using tips from this post: [How to use Poco::ZIP to compress/decompress zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499803/how-to-use-pocozip-to-compress-decompress-zip-file/59500334#59500334)

I have figured out how to recursively compress a folder with this code snippet:

```
    // Now that we have an output file name, compress
    std::ofstream fos(z_file, std::ios::binary);
    Poco::Zip::Compress c(fos, true);
    Poco::File aFile(file_path);
    if (aFile.exists()) {
        Poco::Path p(aFile.path());
        if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
            c.addRecursive(p, Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_AUTO,
                Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_MAXIMUM, true);
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File not found... \r\n";
    }
    // Just in case these don't get called above.
    c.close(); // MUST be done to finalize the Zip file
    fos.close();
    return z_file;
}
```

My question is that once the code gets to,

```
c.addRecursive(p, Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_AUTO,
                Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_MAXIMUM, true);
```

the program continues to run normally, and does compress the folder just fine. However, the program does not return to normal execution flow. Is it going off on a thread and not coming back? I have researched that I can get an update about files being added to the archive through

```
Poco::FIFOEvent<const ZipLocalFileHeader> EDone;
```

It also says that closing the file is essential to creating the archive, but seems that with addRecursive my close() never gets called.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Still getting back to C++ after a while off, but it was the way that I was calling the function where this code resides.

In the code that calls this, I was using:

```
std::string send_file { fh.compress_folder(home_dir) };
```

When I changed it to:

```
std::string send_file = fh.compress_folder(home_dir);
```

Then added a try/catch to the above code as:

```
    std::ofstream fos(z_file, std::ios::binary);
    Poco::Zip::Compress c(fos, true);
    Poco::File aFile(file_path);
    if (aFile.exists()) {
        Poco::Path p(aFile.path());
        if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                c.addRecursive(p, Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_AUTO,
                    Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_MAXIMUM, true);
            } catch(const Poco::Exception e) {
                std::cout << e.what() << "/r/n";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File not found... \r\n";
    }
    // Just in case these don't get called above.
    c.close(); // MUST be done to finalize the Zip file
    fos.close();
    return z_file;
```

Now, the program properly returns and does not travel off into lala land any more.